# Javascript put a variable into a regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I have a text from a message in a varaible:

```
const text =
        "I don't know @Dondes but it did.  It's the highest scoring game in history.";
```

I have a regex to check the mention of a name: `let regex ="\@\Dondes\b"`

I would put the name to check into a variable and use it in the regex like this:

```
let test = "Dondes";
const userName = `\@\${test}}\b`;
```

And after that keep the name like that:

```
text.match(userName)
```

But it didn't work ^^
How can I do that?

Comment: why is there a \ before `\D`??

Comment: ``const userName = String.raw`@${test}\b`;``

Comment: Perfect @WiktorStribiżew thx ;)